# I have a json in assets folder and i would like to parse image from that text file i parsed user names from json please help me to parse a image

Tags: android

This is my MainActivity.java file here i am parsing firstName and lastName of the user but i don't know how to parse the image from this text file. Here is a code that i have try.

package com.jsonparsing;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text, name, llname, txt2;
    TableLayout tableLayout;
    ImageView imv;
    String jsonurl;
    ListView list;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    /*
     * ArrayList<String> web = new ArrayList<String>(); ArrayList<String>
     * lastname = new ArrayList<String>(); ArrayList<ImageView> imagesid = new
     * ArrayList<ImageView>();
     */
    // AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        // CODE FOR JSON PARSING(CORRECT CODE)

        imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        // tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
        // name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        // llname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        // txt2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview2);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                    "det.txt")));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        jsonurl = sb.toString();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsonurl);
            JSONArray jarray = jsonobj.getJSONArray("employees");
            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject childjson = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String fname = childjson.getString("firstName");
                String lname = childjson.getString("lastName");
                String image = childjson.getString("image");
                // firstname.add(fname);
                // lastname.add(lname);
                // text.setVisibility();
                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream istr;
                try {
                    Log.e("", "iiimmmmaaageeee");
                    istr = assetManager.open(image);
                    Log.e("" + istr, "isteisteristr");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
                    imv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    istr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                text.append("First Name:" + "\t" + fname + "\n" + "Last Name:"
                        + "\t" + lname + "\n\n");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); TableRow titles = new
         * TableRow(this); TableRow.LayoutParams params = new
         * TableRow.LayoutParams(
         * android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         * android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
         * params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1); // Creates thin margins so that the
         * content is more readable titles.addView(createTextView("FirstName",
         * params)); titles.addView(createTextView("LastName", params));
         * tableLayout.addView(titles, params); for (int i = 0; i <
         * firstname.size(); i++) { TableRow row = new TableRow(this); // Each
         * row contains one firstname and lastname TextView f_name =
         * createTextView(firstname.get(i), params); row.addView(f_name);
         * TextView l_name = createTextView(lastname.get(i), params);
         * row.addView(l_name); tableLayout.addView(row, params); } }
         * 
         * private TextView createTextView(String str,
         * android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams params) { TextView text = new
         * TextView(this); text.setLayoutParams(params); // Applies the layout
         * params text.setPadding(4, 4, 10, 4); text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         * text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         * // The text is centered on the right text.setText(str); return
         * (text);
         */

        /*
         * try { // get input stream InputStream ims =
         * assetManager.open("ic_launcher.png");
         * 
         * // create drawable from stream Drawable d =
         * Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
         * 
         * // set the drawable to imageview imv.setImageDrawable(d); }
         * catch(IOException ex) { return; }
         */

    }
```

Comment: can you post the json?

Comment: `how to parse the image from this text file.` That suggest that the image is contained in the json file. But the code is only for parsing a filename from the json. And then the code tries to extract the imagefile from assets.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the image loader class I really forget where I got this. But here you go:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler = new Handler();// handler to display images in UI thread

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {

        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(url, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                decodedString.length);

        if (decodedByte != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

        } else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(url, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                decodedString.length);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                    decodedString.length);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();

    }

}
```

make an object of image loader class and copy like this imageloader.DisplayImage(Your jsonvforvpicture, Imageview or what ever you want); and also you need the second class of memory cache

```
public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));// Last
                                                                                // argument
                                                                                // true
                                                                                // for
                                                                                // LRU
                                                                                // ordering
    private long size = 0;// current allocated size
    private long limit = 1000000;// max memory in bytes

    public MemoryCache() {
        // use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit) {
        limit = new_limit;

    }

    public Bitmap get(String id) {
        try {
            if (!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            // NullPointerException sometimes happen here
            // http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78
            return cache.get(id);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(id))
                size -= getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size += getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        if (size > limit) {
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter = cache.entrySet().iterator();

// least
                                                                                // recently
                                                                                // accessed
                                                                                // item
                                                                                // will
                                                                                // be
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // first
                                                                                // one
                                                                                // iterated
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry = iter.next();
                size -= getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if (size <= limit)
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try {
            // NullPointerException sometimes happen here
            // http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78
            cache.clear();
            size = 0;
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap == null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }  
this is the running classes of my project
}
```